# PHP for loop duplicating on page refresh

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a 2d array which I am displaying in a for loop.  The code for this is here:

```
foreach($products as $id => $product) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><a href='./index.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['Book_Code'] . "</a></td>
            <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>$" . $product['Title'] . "</td> 
            <td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>" . $product['Author'] . "</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

I have two items currently in my 2d array (eventually there will be 20).  When i load the page my table correctly displays the two items, #1 & #2.  If i refresh the page #1&#2 are still there but also duplicated underneath so the table looks like

#1
 #2
 #1
 #2

and this occurs again and again on every refresh.  How can i get this to reset everytime a new page is opened?  My table currently has 26 items and growing and its become very difficult to test the rest of my code with this broken.

EDIT:

I am populating my databse like this:

```
$db = sqlite_open ("products.db", 0666, $error);

@sqlite_query($db,"CREATE TABLE Books (Book_Code integer PRIMARY KEY, Author varchar(20), Title varchar(20), Brief_Synopsis varchar2(100), ISBN_Number integer, Publisher varchar(20), imgNumber integer)",$sqliteerror);


sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO Books (Author, Title, Brief_Synopsis, ISBN_Number, Publisher, imgNumber) VALUES ( 'Robin Nixon', 'Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript: With jQuery, CSS & HTML5','Build interactive data-driven websites with the potent combination of open-source technologies and web standards', 9781491918661, 'O&#39Reilly', '001')");
sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO Books (Author, Title, Brief_Synopsis, ISBN_Number, Publisher, imgNumber) VALUES ( 'Reiersol et al', 'PHP in action','This book takes on the most important challenges of web programming in PHP', 9781932394757, 'Greenwich', '002')");




$result=sqlite_query($db,"SELECT * from Books");
$products = array();
while($row=sqlite_fetch_array($result,SQLITE_ASSOC))
{
    $products[] = $row;
}

sqlite_close($db);
```

Comment: Do you have some code elsewhere on the page that populates a demo database or such? It looks like you populate some items into a persistent storage each request. Some leftover testing code?

Comment: Sorry, I have added my sqlite db code to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is quite simple.

Remove the lines:

```
@sqlite_query($db,"CREATE TABLE Books (Book_Code integer PRIMARY KEY, Author varchar(20), Title varchar(20), Brief_Synopsis varchar2(100), ISBN_Number integer, Publisher varchar(20), imgNumber integer)",$sqliteerror);


sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO Books (Author, Title, Brief_Synopsis, ISBN_Number, Publisher, imgNumber) VALUES ( 'Robin Nixon', 'Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript: With jQuery, CSS & HTML5','Build interactive data-driven websites with the potent combination of open-source technologies and web standards', 9781491918661, 'O&#39Reilly', '001')");
sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO Books (Author, Title, Brief_Synopsis, ISBN_Number, Publisher, imgNumber) VALUES ( 'Reiersol et al', 'PHP in action','This book takes on the most important challenges of web programming in PHP', 9781932394757, 'Greenwich', '002')");
```

Or comment them for future use. Each request you are inserting into a database.
The `@` sign in front of the create table suppresses the error you get that the table `Books` already exists. So the table won't be created 'again' and the records will still insert

You could also encapsulate this entire block in a check whether the table exists. If it does not exist, then create an populate with 2 rows so you can test.

### How to check if the table exists

```
$tableCheck = sqlite_array_query($db, "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='Books'");

if(1 > count($tableCheck)) {

     sqlite_query($db,"CREATE TABLE Books (Book_Code integer PRIMARY KEY, Author varchar(20), Title varchar(20), Brief_Synopsis varchar2(100), ISBN_Number integer, Publisher varchar(20), imgNumber integer)",$sqliteerror);

    sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO Books (Author, Title, Brief_Synopsis, ISBN_Number, Publisher, imgNumber) VALUES ( 'Robin Nixon', 'Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript: With jQuery, CSS & HTML5','Build interactive data-driven websites with the potent combination of open-source technologies and web standards', 9781491918661, 'O&#39Reilly', '001')");
    sqlite_query($db,"INSERT INTO Books (Author, Title, Brief_Synopsis, ISBN_Number, Publisher, imgNumber) VALUES ( 'Reiersol et al', 'PHP in action','This book takes on the most important challenges of web programming in PHP', 9781932394757, 'Greenwich', '002')");
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you I understand your answer; everytime my page is refreshed it creates two new products in the books table.  I guess i am slightly confused with the sql code.  If I do take those lines out, when I run the program from start again wont my table be empty because there is nothing in the database?  I guess what I am asking is how can I create and store my books into an sqlite database without it activating the code everytime my page resets?  is there a way to get a line to only activate once or a check if table exists then skip?

Comment: A database is a persistent storage. So until you write code that explicitly removes the books or when your remove the database file itself, the contents of the table will remain unchanged. No amounts of time or number of request influence that fact.

Comment: Your table check gives me the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE in K:\wwwroot\books.php on line 15`.  Line 15 is just `} catch (SQLException e) {`.

Comment: I updated to a simple solution which checks differently. Does that one work?

Comment: Sorry, it does not!  I get the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in K:\wwwroot\books.php on line 11`.  Line 11 is `$tableCheck = $sqlite->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='Books'");` 

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: So sorry man. I pulled an example from the OOP approach, but you are not using that. Updated again.